# Determine time period since event (up to n leads/lags)

Tags: stata

I want to measure the number of periods (here years) since an event occurred (here represented by indicator variable `pos`) up to a given number of leads and lags (here three).

The following code works, but seems hackish and like I'm missing something fundamental. Is there a more robust solution that takes advantage of built in functions or a better logic? I'm on 11.2. Thanks!

```
version 11.2
clear

* generate annual data
set obs 40
generate country = cond(_n <= 20, "USA", "UK")
bysort country: generate year = 1766 + _n
generate pos = 1 if (year == 1776)

* generate years since event (up to three)
encode country, generate(countryn)
xtset countryn year
generate time_to_pos = 0 if (pos == 1)
forvalues i = 1/3 {
    replace time_to_pos = `i' if (l`i'.pos == 1)
    replace time_to_pos = -1 * `i' if (f`i'.pos == 1)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clear question.

This can be shortened. Here is one way. Starting with your code to set up a sandpit

```
version 11.2
clear
* generate annual data
set obs 40
generate country = cond(_n <= 20, "USA", "UK")
bysort country: generate year = 1766 + _n
```

Now it is

```
gen time_to_pos = year - 1776 if  abs(1776 - year) <= 3
```

That is all that seems needed for your example. If you want to generalise to multiple events within each panel, I'd like to know the rules for such events.

I was going to show a trick from http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=dm0055 but it doesn't appear needed.

Comment: Actually, implementing this I realized a problem. Not every dummy is 1776 and varies by country (about 30 countries). Do you think there's a way that I can reference the `if` condition to `pos`?

Comment: Generalise from 1776 to a variable name?

Comment: The event year is indicated by `1` in `pos`. And this year won't be the same for every country in the panel. My example isn't that great. Maybe I should have had USA as 1776 and UK as 1777 because all 30 or so countries have their own (independent) shocks. Ultimately I want to align all the countries by even year and look at the preceding and following years.

Comment: If the event in question is indicated by 1, then `egen event_year = total(year / (pos == 1)), by(country)` produces the variable I had in mind. This _is_ a trick in http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=dm0055